# Internal Error when attempting to set thermostat heat setpoint

Tags: nest-device-access

I am trying to control my thermostats heat setpoint, but am getting an internal error every time I try to set the heat setpoint. The thermostat is in heat mode and I can control the heat setpoint from the Google Home App. This is happening with a Nest Thermostat and Nest Learning Thermostat.

command:

```
{
    "command": "sdm.devices.commands.ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint.SetHeat",
    "params": {
        "heatCelcius": 20.0
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Internal error encountered.",
        "status": "INTERNAL"
    }
}
```

Is there any way to debug what is happening? I have tried to remove and set up the thermostats again, but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and recreate through Postman, it usually gives more information on the why

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm in part agree with you, but first could you push a link to postman for example, and second this is not really an answer ;)

Comment: Just trying to be helpful. Had a number of these generic errors myself and Google pushes more info into other status fields. You will see these in Postman if you use the url that is being sent in the program together with bearer token and the request. Will put this into the comment in the future and not piost it as an answer ;-)